# Any free vncs with relative mouse input?

Tags: linux, windows, gentoo, vnc, software-rec

I have a gentoo tigervnc-server that I use to connect to my pc from work to slack off, the main problem is that I cannot play anything 3D, this is due to tigervnc using a absolute mouse input, It seems there are some plans to add it in the future but its not here yet, my questions are

1. **What vnc server/client are there that support the above mentioned?** I know RealVNC supports but I cannot find anything about it being supported on the free tier (ill ask their support and update you), and even if it does support, are there any foss alternatives?
2. **Do I need to change anything in my server, or will using tigervnc-server and another client be ok?** From my understanding of vnc the answer is most likely a yes, but i figured id ask
3. **Is VNC even the best option?** I don't seem to have any problems with delay or lag like others have mentioned, but are there any better alternatives that I can use.